# How to install wine on parrot os

Tags: linux, windows, operating-system, wine, parrot

I am trying to install wine on parrot  but when I run it I get an error that tells me that I don't have `wine32` installed and when I try to install it I get the error "Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages" I tried with the command "`sudo aptitude -f install wine32`" and it gave me another solution "`Note: selecting "wine32:i386" instead of the virtual package "wine32`".
`The following NEW packages will be installed: wine32:i386{b}`" but it doesn't solve my problem, my system is compatible with `CPU on-mode(s) 32 , 64 bit architecture x86_x64`

how to install wine or run windows apps on parrot Linux